# Limit data query and get only last 1000 rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, nhibernate

I am using linq to nhibernate to query data from large table. I am trying to limit my data query and get only last 1000 rows and only then make filtering, sorting and pagin.

When i try to use .Take() i got an error:

```
unable to locate HQL query plan in cache; generating (.Count[X4Data.Entity.IEventView](.OrderBy[X4Data.Entity.IEventView,System.DateTime](.Take[X4Data.Entity.IEventView](.Where[X4Data.Entity.IEventView](NHibernate.Linq.NhQueryable`1[X4Data.Entity.IEventView], Quote((x, ) => (Equal(x.DeviceId, p1))), ), p2, ), Quote((c5d4d87c-87ba-4e91-9652-bcdc87e3f0ba, ) => (c5d4d87c-87ba-4e91-9652-bcdc87e3f0ba.AtmTime)), ), ))
```

My code:

```
query = query.Take(rowCount);
query = query.ApplyFiltering(cmd, binder);
query = query.ApplySorting(cmd, binder);
binder.TotalCount = query.Count();
query = query.ApplyPaging(cmd);
```

Thanks a lot and sorry for my bad english

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/9773/optimizing-liststring-performance-in-c/9777#9777

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
query.OrderByDescending(criteria).Take(rowCount).OrderBy(criteria)
```

Answer (score 2):

**You can use this:**

```
list.Skip(Math.Max(0, list.Count() - N)).Take(N);
```

**Example:**

Here a List is created that contains 9999 values and selects the last 1000 values via **LINQ**.

```
 List<int> list = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 9999; i++)
        {
            list.Add(i);
        }
        int take = 1000;
        var result = list.Skip(Math.Max(0, list.Count() - take)).Take(take);
```

Answer (score 1):

using ICriteria
try this:

```
    criteria.SetMaxResults(1000);
    criteria.AddOrder(Order.Desc("ID"));
```